# SQL Query- Only display not null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't want to retrieve all rows if all columns( Start Date, Start Date2, Start Date3) have null values

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Id   | Start Date | Start Date2 | Start Date3 |
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ABC123 | 10/15/2021 | null        | null        |
| ABC123 | null       | null        | null        |
| ABC125 | 10/15/2021 | null        | null        |
| ABC126 | null       | null        | 10/15/2021  |
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Result expected

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   Id   | Start Date | Start Date2 | Start Date3 |
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ABC123 | 10/15/2021 | null        | null        |
| ABC125 | 10/15/2021 | null        | null        |
| ABC126 | null       | null        | 10/15/2021  |
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `where` clause and check each column:

```
select t.*
from t
where start_date is not null or start_date2 is not null or start_date3 is not null;
```

It seems awkward to have three columns called "start date" in a table.

Comment: A shorthand for columns with compatible types is `... where Coalesce( start_date, start_date2, start_date3 ) is not null;`.

Comment: @HABO yup... better than my first thought.

Comment: @HABO . . . That works, but it is not index/optimizer friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 db<>[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ed99416a52e6e4999f3ca7b365cf4dd9)

```
WITH MyData
     AS (
     SELECT 'ABC123' AS id, CAST('10/15/2021' AS DATE) AS start_date1, CAST(null AS DATE) AS start_date2, CAST(null         AS DATE) AS start_date3 UNION
     SELECT 'ABC123' AS id, CAST(null         AS DATE) AS start_date1, CAST(null AS DATE) AS start_date2, CAST(null         AS DATE) AS start_date3 UNION
     SELECT 'ABC125' AS id, CAST('10/15/2021' AS DATE) AS start_date1, CAST(null AS DATE) AS start_date2, CAST(null         AS DATE) AS start_date3 UNION
     SELECT 'ABC126' AS id, CAST(null         AS DATE) AS start_date1, CAST(null AS DATE) AS start_date2, CAST('10/15/2021' AS DATE) AS start_date3
     )
     SELECT d.id, 
            d.start_date1, 
            d.start_date2, 
            d.start_date3
     FROM MyData AS d
     WHERE NOT(    d.start_date1 IS NULL
               AND d.start_date2 IS NULL
               AND d.start_date3 IS NULL);
```